# Explain a surprisingly simple optimization result

Tags: optimization, intuition, puzzle

The following optimization problem came to my attention as an idealization of the silly browser game [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/), but is representative of a range of strategy games:

> You have an initial production capacity $p_0$ and a number of improvements $A, B, C, \ldots$ to build in some sequence you can choose. Each improvement $X$ has a cost $c_X$ and will take time to build proportional to its cost and inversely proportional to your capacity. When finished it will increase your production capacity by a given amount $p_X$. You can only build one improvement at a time. Which sequence should you build in in order to get all improvements as quickly as possible?

To get a handle on this I started looking at the case where there are only two improvements $A$ and $B$. The time it will take us to build $A$ first and then $B$ is $\frac{c_A}{p_0} + \frac{c_B}{p_0+p_A}$, and mutatis mutandis for $B$ first. So you should choose to build $A$ first iff
$$ \frac{c_A}{p_0} + \frac{c_B}{p_0+p_A} < \frac{c_B}{p_0} + \frac{c_A}{p_0+p_B} $$
After a bit of algebra (assuming the various parameters are positive, etc.) this turns out to be equivalent to
$$ \tag{*} \frac{c_A}{p_0} + \frac{c_A}{p_A} < \frac{c_B}{p_0} + \frac{c_B}{p_B} $$
This condition has the nice property that all $A$s are on one side of the inequality and all $B$s are on the other. This hints of a solution for the case with more than two improvements, at least heuristically: Compute $c_X/p_0 + c_X/p_X$ for each improvement and start by building the $X$ with the lowest value. Afterwards, repeat the computation with a new $p_0$.

This question is about is the expression
$$\frac{c_X}{p_0} + \frac{c_X}{p_X} = c_X\Bigl(\frac1{p_0}+\frac1{p_X}\Bigr)$$
It is suspiciously simple in light of the maze of algebra that me to it. My question is: **Is there an intuitive way to understand that this expression is the right thing to compare?**

The $c_X/p_X$ term is easy enough to understand: it is the cost per unit of added productivity we pay for building $X$. But what about $c_X/p_0$?

The effect of $c_X/p_0$ makes *qualitative* sense: In the limit of $p_0$ small this term dominates over the $c_X/p_X$ terms, and (*) reduces to comparing $c_A<c_B$. In other words when we have very little initial production capacity the important thing is to get *something* built as quickly as possible, and then the other will take comparatively little time. On the other hand, in the limit of *large* $p_0$s, the $c_X/p_0$ terms vanishe and we're left comparing $c_A/p_A$ with $c_B/p_B$. Then we should just buy the improvement that gives us most bang for the buck first. That makes intuitive sense too.

But *between* those two limits, why is $c_X/p_0$ the right adjustment term? What does it represent intuitively?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Sigh. Of course simply writing down the question made me think enough about it to see the solution, but not before I'd already posted the question. Move along, nothing to see here).*

Somehow it had escaped me that the $\frac{c_A}{p_0}$ term is there in *both* inequalities. It is simply the time it will take for improvement $A$ to be finished. In the same language $\frac{c_A}{p_A}$ is the time it will take for improvement $A$ to produce enough to pay for its own production cost *after* it is finished.

That makes perfect intuitive sense.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether looking for physical meaning makes much sense here because swapping of A and C in the ABC sequence is governed by a completely different law, which does also depend on the B parameters. An interesting problem, by the way! I have no idea how to do the general case...

An example:

Put $c_1=4/3, p_1=1, p_0=p_2=p_3=c_2=c_3=2$.   This gives $c_1(\frac 1{p_0}+\frac 1{p_1})=c_2(\frac 1{p_0}+\frac 1{p_2})=c_3(\frac 1{p_0}+\frac 1{p_3})=2$,   which means that no particular choice of the first step has any advantage according to the "heuristic strategy", and if we decrease $c_1$ just a tiny bit, it becomes the choice to make.

However, every order starting with $c_1$ currently gives $\frac 46+\frac 23+\frac 25=\frac{26}{15}=\frac 53+\frac 1{15}$ and every order ending with $c_1$ gives $\frac 22+\frac 24+\frac 4{18}=\frac{31}{18}=\frac 53+\frac 1{18}$, which is strictly shorter time, so it remains shorter under small perturbations.

Comment: Perhaps better as a comment? :)

Comment: Perhaps... How do you convert?

Comment: If you have a concrete counterexample with three improvements where the heuristic I sketch would make a non-optimal decision, I'd be most interested in seeing it.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Sure. I just posted it. Sorry for the delay :).

Comment: Amazing. (+1) I probably ought to have tried something like that before becoming so enamored with the heuristic.

Answer (score 2):

After hearing about [fedja's counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478494/explain-a-surprisingly-simple-optimization-result/478577#478577), I ran a quick and dirty program looking for other counterexamples to see if I could find one where the scores were not identical. My first suspicion was that the heuristic was bumping into a weird edge case.

Turns out there are a ton of them. Here is one example:

$$p_0=1$$
$$c_1=3,p_1=2$$
$$c_2=4,p_2=7$$
$$c_3=6,p_3=10$$
$$s_n = c_n\Bigl(\frac1{p_0}+\frac1{p_n}\Bigr)$$

Then: $s_1=4.5, s_2\approx4.57, s_3=6.6$ suggesting you should always start with the first choice. However, picking 1, 2, 3 is worse than picking 2, 3, 1:

$$ t_{123} = \frac{3}{1} + \frac{4}{1+2} + \frac{6}{1+2+7} = \frac{74}{15
} = 4.93... $$

$$ t_{231} = \frac{4}{1} + \frac{6}{1+7} + \frac{3}{1+7+10} = \frac{59}{12
} = 4.916... $$

Even though $t_{12} < t_{21}$ and $t_{13} < t_{31}$, $t_{123} > t_{231}$.

Comment: By the way, I finally realized why this heuristic is bad. If you stop measuring the result of the purchase _after_ the first two purchases, t_12 is still better than t_23 (4.33 vs 4.75) but p_12 is still way lower than p_23 (10 vs 18). During the time it takes for the _third_ purchase, the _23 purchase catches up.